# Looping through each cell in a range and updating SAP database

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, export-to-excel

Currently I have values in each cell of a range **"A1:D10"**. I need to copy each cell value at a time into SAP Application and I am using the below code to do that.  But the problem is it is copying one cell (A1) 4 times instead of **A1, B1, C1, D1**.  Once the **A1 to D1** cells are updated into the SAP application, then the data will be saved in the SAP application and macro should start from **B2 to D2** and do the same.  Here is the code that I am using currently.

**Here is the example**

with current code macro is copying (A1) 100 4 times and then moving to (B1) 10 4 times and moving to (C1) 1234 4 times and moving to (D1) BO 4 times, then it will go to row A2 and do the same.

But what I want is it should copy **A1 value 100** into `session.findById("wnd[8]/usr/ctxtANLA-BRSKT1").Text = cell.Value`  and **B1 value 10** into `session.findById("wnd[8]/usr/ctxtANLA-MNSRTS2").Text = cell.Value`  and **C1 value 1234** into  `session.findById("wnd[8]/usr/ctxtANLA-BUHFT3").Text = cell.Value`  and **D1 value BO** into `session.findById("wnd[8]/usr/ctxtANLA-BUYTS4").Text = cell.Value`
[image].

I hope this is more helpful

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim Row As Range
Dim Col As Range

Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = Range("A2:D" & Lastrow)

For Each Row In rng.Rows
    For Each cell In Row.Cells

    If cell.Value <> "" Then

        session.findById("wnd[8]/usr/ctxtANLA-BRSKT1").Text = cell.Value
        session.findById("wnd[8]/usr/ctxtANLA-MNSRTS2").Text = cell.Value
        session.findById("wnd[8]/usr/ctxtANLA-BUHFT3").Text = cell.Value
        session.findById("wnd[8]/usr/ctxtANLA-BUYTS4").Text = cell.Value

    End If

Next cell

Next Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: It shouldn't be doing that. Are you sure your procedure where this code is stored is not being called 4 times?

Comment: Also instead of looping through every cell in the range, it would be faster if you store the range in an array and then transfer the data to the DB. Not that it matters in this case as `A1:D10` is a very small range...

Comment: It is just an example, sometimes we will have more than 1000 rows.  I have noticed that once it enter into the For loop it copies the same value for all four fields because it is within the loop, but I don't know how to change the code to work

Comment: Previously we had only one cell in SAP, but now they have included 3 more cells.  So I have added three more lines to the vba code.  I know that I made a mistake in the code, because I used **Next Cell** after copying all four cell values, but not sure how to change the cell value each time

Comment: I think the same cell value is being copied four time in my code (Please see below)

Comment: `session.findById("wnd[8]/usr/ctxtANLA-BRSKT1").Text = cell.Value`
        `session.findById("wnd[8]/usr/ctxtANLA-MNSRTS2").Text = cell.Value`
        `session.findById("wnd[8]/usr/ctxtANLA-BUHFT3").Text = cell.Value`
        `session.findById("wnd[8]/usr/ctxtANLA-BUYTS4").Text = cell.Value`

Comment: Can you update your question with the EXACT code that you are using? I can't read comments in code

Comment: Siddharth, I have just seen your screen shot. It works fine only for one row.  Here I have 4 rows of code, but the same cell value is being copied for all four lines and then it is moving to the next cell.

Comment: `session.findById("wnd[8]/usr/ctxtANLA-BRSKT1").Text = cell.Value **should be 100**` `session.findById("wnd[8]/usr/ctxtANLA-MNSRTS2").Text = cell.Value **should be 10**`  `session.findById("wnd[8]/usr/ctxtANLA-BUHFT3").Text = cell.Value **should be 1234**` `session.findById("wnd[8]/usr/ctxtANLA-BUYTS4").Text = cell.Value **should be BO**`

Comment: I think I understood your query now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are trying (**Untested**)?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim i As Long, Lastrow As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    With ActiveSheet
        Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To Lastrow 
            If .Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then _
            session.findById("wnd[8]/usr/ctxtANLA-BRSKT1").Text = .Cells(i, 1).Value

            If .Cells(i, 2).Value <> "" Then _
            session.findById("wnd[8]/usr/ctxtANLA-MNSRTS2").Text = .Cells(i, 2).Value

            If .Cells(i, 3).Value <> "" Then _
            session.findById("wnd[8]/usr/ctxtANLA-BUHFT3").Text = .Cells(i, 3).Value

            If .Cells(i, 4).Value <> "" Then _
            session.findById("wnd[8]/usr/ctxtANLA-BUYTS4").Text = .Cells(i, 4).Value
        Next i
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

For a large range, I would still recommend using an array instead of looping through rows as I mentioned in the 2nd comment below your question.

Comment: Please give me 5 minutes.  I will check and let you know

Comment: I have removed unnecessary code. I have updated the above post. Please refresh the page before using the code :)

Comment: Sure.  I am just testing it now

Comment: Hi Siddharth,  This is what I wanted.  I have just tested the code, but not sure why the Asset number column values are not getting updated into SAP field and rest of the columns are updating correctly.  Any idea on this?

Comment: Sorry Siddharth.  It was my mistake.  It is working perfectly fine.  You're the best :).  Thank you so much for your help.